# search for a string in an enumerate if successful perform another search python

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I have the following code:

```
with open("daily_rebar_test.txt", "w") as f2 :
  for index, i in enumerate(f):
    if regex.search(ignorecase, i):
        f2.writelines(f[index:index+1])
        f2.writelines("\n")
        index +=1

        if regex.search("Journal", i, index, index+1 ):
             f2.writelines(f[index:index+1])
             f2.writelines("\n")
             index +=1
```

What i need it to do is search for precompiled case, if it finds it, it writes the line to a new txt file.
After the line is written successfully I need it to perform another search using a new parameter("Journal"), for each case encountered it would need to write it to the new file; when "Journal" is no longer encountered I need it to go back and perform the initial search.

Currently the code finds the precompiled case but because it doesn't increment the index correctly when it tries to search for "Journal" it's still on the old line. Even if it could perform the search for Journal it would do it only once and then go back to the initial search. Somehow i need a for loop within a for loop but I just can't seem to figure out how the syntax should be written.

Thanks,
Cristian

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're doing but this looks like a case where you shouldn't use enumerate, but just increment your index manually.

Comment: If i modify `for index, i in enumerate(f)` to `for index in f` it will give an error:     index +=1
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Why would you change it like that? In your code, `i` is the element in `f`; as I said, you should continue to iterate with `i`, but set `index` manually.

Comment: I tried doing that with `index=+1` but `i` doesn't increment and remains behind

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the script to work using the following code:
     'ignorecase = regex.compile(data_keyword_search, regex.IGNORECASE)

```
f = open(data_path_to_suite).read().splitlines()

with open(data_path_to_save, "w") as f2:
    enum = enumerate(f)
    found_custom_directory = False
    for index, line in enum:
         if regex.search(ignorecase, line):
             f2.writelines(f[index:index+1])
             f2.writelines("\n")
             found_custom_directory = True

#
         else:
             if regex.search("Directory", line):
                 found_custom_directory = False
             if found_custom_directory == True:
                 if regex.search("Journal", line):
                     f2.writelines(f[index:index+1])
                     f2.writelines("\n")'
```